# Role-Based default starting View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been able to find several examples on role based authentication, but this isn't an authentication issue. I have three user types, one of which I want to have a different default starting page. Route-config is initialized before the the user information is available.

In a nut shell: If Role A or Role B start below

```
Controller: Home 
Action: Index
```

else:

```
Controller: Other
Action: OtherIndex
```

Where and how should this be implemented?

**EDIT**

This should only occur the first time the site is accessed, the other users can go to Home/Index, just not by default.

**EDIT**

Using Brad's Suggestion I created a redirect attribute with his redirection logic, and applied it to Index. I then created another action for the page. This way if I do need to allow access to the HomeIndex I can specifically assign it with Home/HomeIndex, and anything that uses the default routing can hit the Home/Index

```
[RedirectUserFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return HomeIndex();
}
```

For those who need it - here is the Attribute

```
 public class RedirectUserFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
        {

            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Role A") 
            && !HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Role B"))
            {
               actionContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
               new RouteValueDictionary {
                           { "Controller", "OtherController" }, 
                           { "Action", "OtherAction" } });
             }

          }
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (
            !User.IsInRole("Something") &&
            !User.IsInRole("Role B")
        ) return RedirectToAction("OtherIndex");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Same goes for `OtherController`.

Alternatively you could create your own [`ActionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that looks for a conventionally-named action (like `IndexRolename` over `Index`)

Comment: I don't always want to redirect, just the first time the site is accessed

Comment: I'd say the `ActionFilter` or `AuthorizationFilter` would be the better way to go so you could apply your rule across all requests and not have to add the code to each action method.

Comment: @Seth: you can monitor the request using a session or a profile flag; your call.

Comment: @Brad - I'm missing a piece here, this is great for making sure Index **Always** Redirects. I'm trying to do it on 'app start' only. Would creating a Default Action with this logic be your suggestion, that way the other users need to direct Home/index they can?

Comment: @Seth I believe Brad answered before you updated the question to say you only want to check on the first access.  As they said in their comment above you will need to track that it is their first access somewhere like the session or profile table in the database.  You can check/set this flag on application start, or maybe better, session start, then I would say use a custom `ActionFilter` or `AuthorizationFilter` to check the flag after routing has been applied and redirect if necessary.